# Error handling python

Tags: python, sockets, networking

Trying to do a simple error handling to see if the host is unreachable and I keep getting an invalid syntax on except.

```
import socket               

s = socket.socket()         
host = "" 
port = 1337             

print("""
============================================
Welcome to Coder77's local internet messager
 ============================================
The current soon to be encrypted server is {0}
""".format(host))

host = input("Please select the IP you would like to communicate to: ")
print("Now connecting to {0}....".format(host))

try:
      s.connect((host, port)
except socket.error as s:
      print ("Host is unreachable")


print (s.recv(2048))
input("Close")
s.close()
```

Comment: Rule of thumb: whenever you get a weird Syntax Error, take a look at the *preceding* line to see if your parenthesis, braces and brackets are balanced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
s.connect((host, port)
```

should be

```
s.connect((host, port))
```

Answer (score 3):

change the `s.connect((host, port)` to `s.connect(host, port)`

Comment: No, it should be `s.connect((host, port))`. [`socket.connect()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.connect) takes just *one* argument.